# WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn Edit on Key press

Tags: wpf, combobox, datagrid, keypress

I have a datagrid with a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` in it.

I want my users to be able to enter edit mode by just typing.
This is the default behavior for `DataGridTextColumn` and I don't like that they have to press F2 in order to enable editing for just this column type.

How can I make the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` enter edit mode without them needing to press F2? Ideally on Key Press, but I would be fine if it entered edit mode on focus as well.

**Solution**
Modifications to the accepted answer that bring back the basic functionality of the datagrid:

```
 void Cell_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == Key.Enter || e.Key == Key.Tab)
        {
            dgBins.CommitEdit();
            dgBins.SelectedIndex += 1;
        }else if(e.Key.ToString().Length == 1 
            || (e.Key.ToString().StartsWith("D") && e.Key.ToString().Length == 2)
            || e.Key.ToString().StartsWith("NumPad")
            || e.Key == Key.Delete 
            || e.Key == Key.Back )
        { 
            if (e.OriginalSource is DataGridCell)
            {
                DataGridCell cell = (sender as DataGridCell);
                Control elem = FindChild<Control>(cell, null);
                elem.Focus();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
         <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
             <EventSetter Event="PreviewKeyDown" Handler="Cell_PreviewKeyDown"/>
             <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="Cell_GotFocus"/>
         </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Handlers :

```
void Cell_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource is DataGridCell)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = (sender as DataGridCell);
        Control elem = FindChild<Control>(cell, null);
        elem.Focus();
    }
}

void Cell_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell cell = (sender as DataGridCell);
    cell.IsEditing = true;
}
```

Helper :

```
public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
        where T : DependencyObject
{
    // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
    if (parent == null) return null;

    T foundChild = null;

    int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        // If the child is not of the request child type child
        T childType = child as T;
        if (childType == null)
        {
            // recursively drill down the tree
            foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

            // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
            if (foundChild != null) break;
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
        {
            var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
            // If the child's name is set for search
            if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
            {
                // if the child's name is of the request name
                foundChild = (T)child;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // child element found.
            foundChild = (T)child;
            break;
        }
    }

    return foundChild;
}
```

If this solves your problem.

Comment: This almost works, I had to modify it so that it ignores the enter, escape, and tab keys.  Also,  Now the user has to press enter twice to go to the next row... trying to figure out how to stop that.

Comment: @MrZander That is a candidate for a separate question. So request u to ask separately. And if this answer your present question mark it accordingly.

Comment: Well sure, this does cause it to go into edit mode, but it breaks pretty much all other functionality of the datagrid.  Less than ideal.  At any rate, I have updated the question with my modifications that fix the issue.

Comment: @MrZander If you try to modify default behavior of a extremely complex control like DataGrid, then you have to do lot many things.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `SelectedCellsChanged` event. It works on focus changing.

If you don't want that behaviour on other columns you can check `e.AddedCells[0].Column` property (if your `SelectionUnit="Cell"` of `DataGrid`).

```
private void dgTest_SelectedCellsChanged( object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e )
{
    ( sender as DataGrid ).BeginEdit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer might be a little late but I want to add this, because no given answer was solving the problem for me without breaking normal DataGrid keyboard handling.

The question is simple:

> I want my users to be able to enter edit mode by just typing.

So is the solution:

```
<DataGrid KeyDown="DataGrid_KeyDown">
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

With code in code behind xaml.cs:

```
private void DataGrid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dg = (sender as DataGrid);
    if (dg.CurrentColumn is DataGridComboBoxColumn)
    {
        dg.BeginEdit();
    }
}
```

Because this already is the normal behavior of TextBoxes I only wanted to apply this to DataGridComboBoxColumn. Of course this will be called on every key press, but a call to 'BeginEdit' does not seem to hurt when the DataGrid already is in edit mode.